# Multiple Mysqli insert in one form submit

Tags: php, database, mysqli

Im trying to save the data that a user is filling in some form.

The problem is when i press the submit button, all the data is saved exactly as i wanted, but it saves it multiple times. (same data in many rows)

```
    <?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
        $share = $_POST['share'];
        $date = $_POST['date'];
        $dealtype = $_POST['dealtype'];
        $enter = $_POST['enter'];
        $exitdeal = $_POST['exitdeal'];
        $no1 = $_POST['no1'];
        $no2 = $_POST['no2'];
        $profit = $_POST['profit'];

        if ($share != "")
        {
            if ($date != "")
            {
                if ($dealtype != "" )
                {
                    if ($enter != "" )
                    {
                        if ($exitdeal != "" )
                        {
                            $mysql = "INSERT INTO markettable (share, date, dealtype, enter, exitdeal, no1, no2, profit) 
                            VALUES ('$share','$date', '$dealtype', '$enter', '$exitdeal', '$no1', '$no2', '$profit')";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $mysqli->query($mysql);
        if ($mysqli->query($mysql) === TRUE) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
        echo "Error: " . $mysql . "<br>" . $mysqli->error;
        }
        $mysqli->close();
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here,

```
  $mysqli->query($mysql);

  if ($mysqli->query($mysql) === TRUE) {
       echo "New record created successfully";
   }
```

`$mysqli->query($mysql);` inserts the data first and `if ($mysqli->query($mysql) === TRUE)` inserts again.

You change your code as,

```
     $result =  $mysqli->query($mysql); // save the result in $result variable
     if ($result === TRUE) { // checks if its successfully inserted
           echo "New record created successfully";
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You call query to execute twice, first time before if statement, and second time inside if statement condition.

Comment: sorry, cant see where i call for query twice
can you show me where the second one?

Comment: On line before if, $mysqli->query($mysql);  and inside condition in if, if ($mysqli->query($mysql) === TRUE). This here is also call to execute mxsql query. Execute query and save result in variable, and then check if that variable is TRUE.

Comment: Check answer from Yuva Ray, it also describes what I've said.